# JSON is being accessed every time even with an invalid key

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ecmascript-6, key-value

So I have a function that has an JSON within it, and it's value consists in a key-pair in which the key is recieved as parameter and the value is the return of another function, like shown below.

```
const normalizeKeyValuePair = (key, value) => {
  const propertyHandler = {
    speed: normalizeSpeed(value),
    actions: normalizeActions(value)
  };

  return [normalizeField(key), propertyHandler[key] || normalizeValue(value)];
};
```

The problem is with the `actions` key. Every single `key` parameter that `normalizeKeyValuePair` recieves is thrown into `actions` and goes to `normalizeActions`. How can I prevent this from happen?

To understand why this is a problem, this is `normalizeActions`. When `actions` is an primitive, JS throws an error.

```
const normalizeActions = actions => {
  const normalizedActions = [];

  for(let action of actions) {
    normalizedActions.push([action.name, action.desc]);
  }

  return normalizedActions;
}
```

Thanks in advance. Let me know if needs more information!

Comment: What should `normalizeActions` return for a primitive?

Comment: It shouldn't be called for a primitive. `normalizeActions` is supposed to be called only for arrays. But when it's called for a primitve, JS throws an error saying that `actions is not iterable`

Comment: What do you want to be put in the `propertyHandler.actions` in that case?

Comment: Perhaps this represents a lack of knowledge on how JS works, but if I try to access `propertyHandler` with an "wrong" key, for example `propertyHandler[name]`, should't I get undefined as response?

Comment: Yes, you do. I'm not sure what that has to do with it.

Comment: Well in this case it get's to a moment that `propertyHandler` is called with `armor_class` key, and somehow it manages to call `normalizeActions`

Comment: I don't really understand the point of the `propertyHandler` object. The only property that matters is the one in `key`, so why do you create other properties?

Comment: It seems like `switch(key) ...` would be a better way to code this.

Comment: It's because you call `normalizeActions(value)` with a value that isn't always an action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time `normalizeKeyValuePair` is invoked, it will call `normalizeActions(value)` when it creates `propertyHandler`.

This should do what you intended:

```
const propertyHandler = {
  speed: normalizeSpeed,
  actions: normalizeActions
};

const normalizeKeyValuePair = (key, value) => {
  const ph = propertyHandler[key];
  return [normalizeField(key), (ph && ph(value)) || normalizeValue(value)];
};
```

Comment: Well that makes a lot of sense now, ty!

Comment: Althought Barmar's response also makes sense, that one is faster according to JSPerf, so I'm picking this one as the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the logic is all wrong. You should check `key` before calling the normalize functions, and only call the appropriate one.

```
const normalizeValuePair(key, value) {
    let normalKey = normalizeField(key);
    let normalValue;
    switch(value) {
        case 'speed':
            normalValue = normalizeSpeed(value);
            break;
        case 'actions':
            normalValue = normvalizeActions(value);
            break;
        default:
            normalValue = normalizeValue(value);
    }
    return [normalKey, normalValue];
}
```

Comment: Well I don't think "wrong" is the word to use here. But help me understand: if I follow cybersam response, how does the `switch(key)` becomes a better way of doing it?

Comment: Yeah, maybe that was harsh, it just seems backwards. You're performing a bunch of normalizations, then using the property test to select the one you want to return. But you can simply do the one normalization you really want.

Comment: cybersam's method is also nice, I just didn't think of it.

Comment: Oh I get it. I'll do some tests to see which solution is faster, and go with the one that wins. Thank you!

Comment: The difference is likely to be negligible. The JS compiler might even convert the switch internally to similar code. Go with whatever seems clearer to you.